# QML: how can i remove double quotes around numbers when converting object to JSON string

Tags: json, qml

When I change the key's value of json file,I find a problem :save as new josn file ,the value always has "" ,but the source json file has not "",i want to remove this "",how could i do?
this is my code:

```
       cutDataOBJ[tableView.model[_row].key].value = value
       fileCon.write(appDir+"./cut3.json",JSON.stringify(cutDataOBJ))
```

the source json file is

```
{
    "z1_spindle_speed": 
    {
        "type": "int",
        "value": 6000    // 6000
    },
 ...
}
```

new json file here

```
{
    "z1_spindle_speed": 
    {
        "type": "int",
        "value": "1000"// "1000"
    },
 ...
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to ***stack overflow***,

It seems that the original `value` type is `string`.
You can do this trick to convert it to a number if it is convertible.

```
cutDataOBJ[tableView.model[_row].key].value = Number.isNaN(value) ? value : Number(value);
```

For certain characters in `value` it may not work properly. For example if `value` is `"."` this will return `null`.